# Find the volume of the solid bounced by the planes $z=0$,$z=y$ and $x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

So I do the following: $$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int_0^{y}  \,dzdydx$$, but the answer gives me $\frac{2}{3}$, as it graphs a cylinder it should be the half of the half of a cylinder of height and radius 1: ($\frac{\pi}{4}$)
[image: see graph]

Comment: You should show some work.

Comment: He did show some work.

Comment: Your answer looks ok to me (though, it only includes the "top portion").  The region does not split the upper half part of the cylinder into two   pieces of equal volume. Calculate your integral with $z$ limits $y$ and  $1$. the "top" has volume $(\pi/2)-2/3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the figure:

$\hspace{7cm}$[image: ![enter image description here]

Note that the volume below the blue plane is not equal to the volume above it.

The volume below the blue plane (as you calculated):
$$B=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int_0^{y}  \,dzdydx=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} y \,dydx=\\
\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{y^2}{2} \big{|}_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}  \,dx=
\int_{-1}^1 \frac12(1-x^2) \,dx=\frac12\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3}\right)|_{-1}^1=\\
\frac12\left[\frac23+\frac23\right]=\frac23.$$
The volume above the blue plane (as noted by David Mitra):
$$A=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int_y^1  \,dzdydx=
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} (1-y) \,dydx=\\
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \,dydx-\int_{-1}^{1}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} y \,dydx=\\
\frac{\pi}2-\frac23.$$
Hence, as expected: 
$$A+B=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$